# TransactionScope with async wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, transactionscope

I can't get transactionScope to roll back, either because I'm missing something or I'm misunderstanding the purpose of transactionScope.

I have the following method that is making a call to two wcf services:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            Task task1 = service1.UpdateAsync(values);

            Task task2 = service2.UpdateAsync(values);

            await Task.WhenAll(task1 , task2);

            scope.Complete();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

Each service operation has the following attributes:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
 void Update(IEnumerable<string> values);
```

The actual service (same for both)

```
public void Update(IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    foreach (string value in values)
    {
        db1Access.Update(value);
    }
}
```

SqlAccess (This is or own library we are using, basically your bread and butter IDbCommand stuff behind this):

```
BaseSqlAccess sqlAccess = factory.CreateSqlAccess("stp_update");
sqlAccess.AddParameter("values", values);

sqlAccess.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The binding in the contract has the following attributes:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpCommonBinding" transactionFlow="true">
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

API's config that implements the service endpoint:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CommonBindingConfiguration" transactionFlow="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000"/>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:56084/service2.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonBindingConfiguration" contract="IService1" name="IService1EndPoint"/>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:56084/service2.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CommonBindingConfiguration" contract="IService2" name="IService2EndPoint"/>
</client>
```

I was under the impression if I throw an error after the Task.WhenAll it would begin a rollback, I've also tried throwing the error in service2 but service1 still follows through and there is no rollback.

What am I missing here?

A few things to note:

- DataAccess is executing Procs
- Each service is connecting to two separate DB's

Comment: Oops sorry my bad

Comment: Can you show the code on the server side that implments the endpoint. There are relevent annotations on those methods too. Also show the binding config on the client side too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've added in the configuration data for the API that implements the service endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you haven't *attributed* the implementation of the WCF service with TransactionScopeRequired as true.

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public void Update(IEnumerable<string> values)
{
    foreach (string value in values)
    {
        db1Access.Update(value);
    }
}
```

More on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.transactionscoperequired(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730232(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This seems to have corrected it from a coding perspective, looks like I still have some MSDTC configuration issues on the servers themselves. thanks.